# HP Pavillon 15 not charging beyond 50% (54%) - HP battery care function issue?

Tags: bios, battery

I have the issue that my (well-aged) HP Pavilion 15 laptop does not charge beyond 54%. The issue might be connected to having the "HP Battery care function" activated before updating the bios. Here is the whole, twisted story:

The original battery, totally undersized for this laptop, died within the first year. I replaced it and searched for options to protect it while having it plugged in most of the time. I don't remember how I solved it back then, but I managed to set a charging limit to 50%. Looking at screenshots on the internet I feel like I recognise the "HP battery care function" found in some bios versions, but cant be quite sure. I never went back to the setting but left it as is for years. Over the years I replaced the HDD, reinstalled windows serveral times and upgraded to win10 and 11, and also updated the bios. At some point, after one of the reinstalls, the charge limit shifted from 50% flat to 54%, which I found odd at the time but didn't investigate.

Now, I attempted to deactivate it to use the laptop more on battery again. Turns out that the battery care function is not available in my current bios, and the Internet claims that it was never available for this model. I'm trying to understand what stops my laptop to charge past 54% then and how to change this. These are my thoughts and troubleshooting attempts:

1. Maybe the battery is simply broken and has only that much capacity left. - possible, and I can't disprove it unless I buy a new one. What speaks against it is that, to drop from 54% to 0%, takes about 30-40min, which is about 50% of the time the full brand new battery ever lasted, and also makes a healthy impression in charging speed etc. Furthermore, the value of 45% has been stable for literal years, which doesn't look like a decay process to me. Different battery health tools, including HP ones, did not detect "problematic" battery wear.
2. If it was any microsoft or third party application rather than a bios setting then it should habe been annihilated with the OS reinstalls or the HDD exchange at least - unless for unknown reason the information is stored on my data partition (D:) rather then windows partition (C:) and therefore copied back in by me accidentally every time. (Actually I'm quite well structured with my data storage there and would be very surprised.
3. Assuming the battery care function was in the bios, and got lost via the update.

3a) what bios version could have been on my machine earlier? Is there an exception where a pavilion 15 could have come with the battery care function? Is there a bios from a related machine that someone knows I can install without bricking my machine? Can I potentially have installed a foreign bios to get access to the function in the first place and been lucky that I didn't brick it? Can I trace something like that back on my device, like does it keep a list of old bios versions?

3b) If not, how can I have my laptop forget forever that such a setting has ever existed? I removed the CMOS battery and got a "invalid checksum - all back to standard" indicating that the procedure worked, but no change on the charging. Is there anything else inside this machine besides the HDD (meanwhile SSD) and CMOS that can store memory in some way and that I could erase?

In summary, I am happy for any potential explanations and advice on further narrowing down or solving the problem.

Device and System Info:

SYSTEM PRODUCT NAME: Hewlett-Packard HP Pavilion 15 Notebook PC

BIOS: F.46 04/18/2018

OS BUILD: 22621.1.amd64fre.ni_release.220506-1250

Processor: AMD A10-5745M APU with Radeon(tm) HD Graphics 2.10 GHz

Installed RAM: 12,0 GB (11,2 GB usable)

Product ID: 00325-80000-00000-AAOEM

System type: 64-bit operating system, x64-based processor

Edition: Windows 11 Home

Version: 22H2

Installed on: ‎17/‎10/‎2022

OS build: 22621.2861

Experience: Windows Feature Experience Pack 1000.22681.1000.0

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at the [battery report](https://uk.pcmag.com/batteries-power/132133/how-to-check-your-laptops-battery-health-in-windows-10)?
That should show design capacity vs actual capacity.

Sometimes you need to run a battery through a full charge discharge cycle to reset it's internal 'charging clock'.
From iFixit - advice for their own batteries, which is similar to that from many battery manufacturers/resellers…

> Charge it to 100% and keep charging it for at least 2 more hours. Then use your device until it shuts off due to low battery. Finally, charge it uninterrupted to 100%.

You can expand this by charging overnight, then leaving it flat overnight & recharging again longer than required. Some manufacturers suggest repeating this several times if you can't persuade the data to settle - however, on a battery already nearing end of life, repetition may not gain you anything.

Comment: I've had charging issues with my mobile phone, and the recalibration is similar. I don't charge up to 100% and keep charging though, but I do drain the battery until it powers off, and then turning it back on until it won't turn on anymore. At that point, I fully charge to 100%. Best way to discharge the battery is to first do it in the OS with all options enabled to discharge it as best as you can, then go into BIOS/recovery where it doesn't do things like turn off screen, and keep it on until it dies.

Comment: @LPChip - you have to be careful you don't drop the [real, not computer-measured] charge to 2% or under, as it may never come back to life if you do.

Comment: @Tetsujin good point, I didn't mention that above! Different battery health tools were either unable to or reported no issue with the battery. The recommended one e.g. suggests 26.995mWh out of 26.995mWh in 242 cycles... I suspect it's the fact that this battery has never (or at least not in the last ~3 years) reached 100% that fools the tool.

Comment: @Tetsujin + LPChip would you guys consider it realistic that a battery chokes at exactly the same percentage for years? I've not purposefully cycled it by draining, but I use this laptop daily and also utilise the (remaining) battery capacity to 0% regularly when travelling with it. I'm slightly hesitant to "violate" it that way but if you see a chance in it i would try. I'm also using a charge limiter on my phone and am aware of the fakt that it takes a few cycles to get back to full 100% capacity!

Comment: @Tetsujin "[real, not computer-measured] charge..." How would I check this?

Comment: If it's incorrectly calibrated, it makes perfect sense. What the battery thinks is 100% is being misinterpreted by the computer. That's why you do the calibration step on first run with a new battery.

Comment: You can't know what the battery knows but the computer doesn't. That's why you have to calibrate it - to get the two in sync. [btw, I would not recommend keeping on forcing it to boot when it's decided the battery is flat.]

Comment: @Egon if the battery stops charging at 50%, then there is a different limit in place. If it charges upto 50% or more, but not go higher while still saying its charging, then the battery calibration is necessary.

Comment: ok I see, that makes sense! I've disabled all Windows "hibernate at 5%" etc to run it down to what windows considers flat, then recharge and maybe repeat a few times tonight. Let's see how that goes or whether I need to discharge it further (i.e. boot into recover)! Thank you guys!

Comment: You need to have patience with this, Charge it for 12 hours, then run it flat without allowing it to sleep [running videos in VLC will do this quickly, it tends to override power saving settings quite aggressively]. Once the computer shuts down, then leave off for 12 hours, then charge it 12 hours. If you rush it, it won't work.

Comment: Hey guys, update: I did two full cycles with more than 12 hours on full and ~4 and ~8 hours on flat respectively. Setting the "critical battery limit" to 0% cause the PC to completely crash on 0% without prior warning rather than going into hibernate. That makes me confident that flat was actually flat. Uncleverly, I didn't another thing in parallel: on the first cycle I also uninstalled the AC-charger driver, which means I can't tell the effects of the two actions apart. The result is that since the first cycle, it only charges to 44%. The second cycle didn't show any effect.

Comment: So might be that either the driver reinstall was the only thing having an effect, or just that the first cycle had an effect and the second no more. Either way, it sucks that I reduced  the percentage further rather than increasing it back to 100%. From the first feel I would say though that it's lasts roughly the same time, so factual capacity is still the same.